# How to build a circuit in a breadboard?

Tags: breadboard, protoboard

Basically, I want to build the following circuit on my breadboard to compare my analytical and my experimental results. The power source is going to be a signal generator. How can I set this up? I am new to building circuits and have no idea how to translate my schematics into a breadboard.

[image]

This is what I mean by breadboard

[image]

Comment: Do you know how breadboards are built? Too broad anyway.

Comment: I do not know. That is why I am asking for help.

Comment: Google should be first stop. First result I got on my search is http://www.instructables.com/id/Breadboards-for-Beginners/

Comment: Thank you. I did stop by Google first. I read basic tutorials like the one you showed, and I understand how the connections are made. I just don't know how to translate a circuit I have on paper to a breadboard. And I could not find any links providing this information.

Comment: There are very many pages that explain how to use breadboards. The very first hit looks good: https://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/references/how-to-use-a-breadboard

Comment: @WarrenHill It is exactly like http://www.ladyada.net/images/arduino/halfbb.jpg. It is the most basic protoboard there is.

Comment: You trying to juice one amp out of a signal generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question isn't looking too promising, just this:-

[image: board2]

Comment: your circuit isn't closed

Comment: @BlairFonville Thanks.  Too hasty with Eraser before the question is closed.

Comment: RG and RF are hard to see